# Dozer - How can i make Dozer copy a value from source to target, even if it already is set in target?

Tags: mapping, dozer

I am using Dozer (5.3.2) to map from a source Person object to a target Person object. The default constructor of the superclass of Person sets a UUID on the object. Because of that, when I map the source to a new Person, the UUID on the new Person is already set, and is thus not copied from the source object. In code (full code further down):

```
DozerBeanMapper MAPPER = // ... see code further down;
Person source = new Person();
Person target = new Person();
MAPPER.map(source, target);
```

What I want: After the call to MAPPER.map(...), I want target.getUuid() to equal source.getUuid(). As of now, they are different (because they are set to UUID.randomUUID in the super constructor, see below).

I could solve this by setting

```
target.setUuid(null);
```

before calling MAPPER.MAP(...), but that is not what I want, as this is a simplification of a more complex problem. Is there some way to configure Dozer or make custom classes so that the mapper sets values in the target object even the value in the target object is not null?

My code is as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    private long uuid;

    public AbstractEntity() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    public AbstractEntity(long uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

        public UUID getUuid()
    {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(final UUID uuid)
    {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

}


public class Person extends AbstractEntity
{
    // Getters and setters...
}
```

Here is the code that creates and execute the dozer mapper:

```
DozerBeanMapper MAPPER = new DozerBeanMapper();
BeanMappingBuilder builder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(UUID.class, UUID.class, TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(), TypeMappingOptions.mapNull(true),
                TypeMappingOptions.beanFactory(UuidBeanFactory.class.getName()));
    }
};
MAPPER.addMapping(builder);

Person source = new Person();
Person target = new Person();
MAPPER.map(source, target);
```

Code for the UUIDBeanFactory - I am using this because UUID does not have an empty constructor, which makes Dozer throw an exception.

```
public class UuidBeanFactory implements BeanFactory
{
    @Override
    public Object createBean(Object sourceObject, Class<?> aClass, String s)
    {
        if (sourceObject == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        UUID source = (UUID) sourceObject;
        UUID target = new UUID(source.getMostSignificantBits(), source.getLeastSignificantBits());

        return target;
    }
}
```